# Failed to instantiate module ngMaterial, although it's in bower.json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, heroku, mean-stack

I'm running into a problem in our MEAN project. We have our environment hosted on heroku. We started using ngMaterial in our project, and this is working fine locally AND when we run this on our staging environment on Heroku. But once I push to our production server, we get the error message: **Failed to instantiate module ngMaterial**.

Our bower.json:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "0.4.0",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "~3",
    "angular": "~1.4",
    "angular-resource": "~1.4",
    "angular-animate": "~1.4",
    "angular-aria": "~1.4",
    "angular-mocks": "~1.4",
    "angular-ui-utils": "bower",
    "angular-ui-router": "0.2.18",
    "angular-file-upload": "1.1.5",
    "bootstrap-ui": "^1.3.2",
    "ng-tasty": "^0.6.1",
    "angular-bootstrap": "^1.3.2",
    "highcharts-ng": "^0.0.11",
    "highcharts": "^4.2.5",
    "angular-bootstrap-colorpicker": "^3.0.25",
    "angular-audio": "^1.7.2",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "angularjs-dropdown-multiselect": "^1.5.2",
    "ng-file-upload": "^12.2.12",
    "angular-moment": "^1.0.1",
    "moment": "2.8.1",
    "font-awesome": "fontawesome#^4.7.0",
    "angular-material": "^1.1.5"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "~1.4",
    "moment": "2.8.1"
  }
}
```

Our modules/core/client/app.config.js :

```
'use strict';

// Init the application configuration module for AngularJS application
var ApplicationConfiguration = (function() {
    // Init module configuration options
    var applicationModuleName = 'mean';
    var applicationModuleVendorDependencies = [
        'ngResource',
        'ngAnimate',
        'ui.router',
        'ui.bootstrap',
        'ui.utils',
        'ngFileUpload',
        'ngTasty',
        'ngAnimate',
        'ngAria',
        'ngMaterial',
        'highcharts-ng',
        'colorpicker.module',
        'ngAudio',
        'angularjs-dropdown-multiselect',
        'angularMoment',
    ];
    // Add a new vertical module
    var registerModule = function(moduleName, dependencies) {
        // Create angular module
        angular.module(moduleName, dependencies || []);
        // Add the module to the AngularJS configuration file
        angular.module(applicationModuleName).requires.push(moduleName);
    };

    return {
        applicationModuleName: applicationModuleName,
        applicationModuleVendorDependencies: applicationModuleVendorDependencies,
        registerModule: registerModule
    };
})();
```

Since I installed the angular material dependency through bower I didn't use the CDN links in the index.html. Could this cause any problems?

Comment: did you run ``bower install`` and add the files to ``<script>``

Comment: I ran bower install locally, and on the server bower install is called by this part of the code in the package.json: "scripts": {
    "start": "grunt",
    "test": "grunt test",
    "postinstall": "bower install --config.interactive=false"
  },